# Open .rtf Attachment and Paste Contents in Current Email Body

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, automation

We have an Access database that is using the `SendObject` method to export the report as an attachment to an email.

What I need to be able to do is open the attachment, copy the text (with formatting) and paste that into the body of the generated email and delete the file.

I've got the code to strip the attachment and open it, but I'm not sure how to copy everything in the Word document and paste it back to the original email.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If there is a simpler approach, please let me know.

```
Sub olAttachmentStrip()
  Dim strFilename As String
  Dim strPath As String
  Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim olAtmt As Outlook.Attachments
  Dim olInspector As Outlook.Inspector
  Dim appWord As Word.Application
  Dim docWord As Word.Document

  strPath = "C:\temp\"

  Set olInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
  If Not TypeName(olInspector) = "Nothing" Then
    If TypeName(olInspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then
        Set olItem = olInspector.CurrentItem
        Set olAtmt = olItem.Attachments
            olAtmt.Item(1).SaveAsFile strPath & olAtmt.Item(1).DisplayName
            strFilename = strPath & olAtmt.Item(1).DisplayName
            'olAtmt.Item(1).Delete
    Else
    MsgBox "Something went horribly wrong."
    End If
  End If

  Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  appWord.Visible = False 
  Set docWord = appWord.Documents.Open(strFilename)
  Stop  '<==  This is where I'm stuck!
  Set docWord = Nothing
  Set appWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you already have the code to extract the attachment. The next step is to simply open the file, copy the complete text and paste it in the current email.

Try this (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim doc As Object, sel As Object
    Dim oWord As Object, oDoc As Object, wRng As Object


    '~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    '~~> If not found then create new instance
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Open the Attachement
    Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\MyDocument.rtf", ConfirmConversions:=False, _
        ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", _
        PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:="", _
        WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:=0, XMLTransform:="", _
        Encoding:=1200)

    '~~> Get the comeplete text and copy it
    Set wRng = oDoc.Range
    wRng.Copy

    '~~> Close word Doc
    oDoc.Close

    '~~> Paste it in active email
    Set doc = ActiveInspector.WordEditor
    Set sel = doc.Application.Selection
    sel.Paste

    '~~> Clean up
    Set wRng = Nothing: Set oDoc = Nothing: Set oWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, but I have one more issue.  I've got the code to strip the attachment, open it, copy the selection and paste back to the original email, but when the email was created (DoCmd.SendObject acReport) the email that was generated was generated as Plain Text and I lose the formatting that I had whenever I create an email that supports HTML formatting.  I'm stumped.  Any assistance or direction would be appreciated.  If there's an easier way to accomplish this, any direction would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not too well versed with MS Access. `DoCmd.SendObject acReport` What is the exact syntax that you are using?

Comment: I don't have it in front of me.  The code produces a .rtf document which contains the formatting.  Whenever I use your code on a new email, formatting is perfect. Whenever I pastes the range back into the Plain Text email generated in Outlook, the .rtf selection loses the formatting.  It makes sense that I could change the formatting of the active email back to Html, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about it. I'll post the syntax in the morning.  Thanks